# Laravel Service won't register

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sail, laravel-service-container

Followed every step from laravel 9 manual, and my service will not register consistently. Don't quite know why but it suddenly breaks and I receive a `Target class [thumbnail] does not exist`error out of nowhere.

Setup

Service:

```
namespace App\Services;

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
  use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

  class ThumbnailService
  {
    public function storeThumbnail($userId, $file, $scale) {
      $thumbnail_image = Image::make($file);
      $orig_width = $thumbnail_image->width();
      $orig_height = $thumbnail_image->height();
      $thumbnail_image->resize($orig_width * $scale, $orig_height * $scale);

      $thumb_stream = $thumbnail_image->stream();
      $thumb_path = env('MIX_AWS_IMAGES_DIRECTORY') . '/'. $userId . '/thumbnails';
      $thumb_file = $thumb_path . '/' . 'thumb_1_4_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
      Storage::disk('s3')->put($thumb_file, $thumb_stream->__toString());
      return $thumb_file;
    }
  }
```

Provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\ThumbnailService;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ThumbnailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
  /**
   * Register services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->singleton('thumbnail', function() {
      return new ThumbnailService();
    });

  }

  /**
   * Bootstrap services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot()
  {

  }

  public function provides()
  {
    return [ThumbnailService::class];
  }
}
```

Facade:

```
namespace App\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Thumbnail extends Facade
{
  protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
    return 'thumbnail';
  }
}
```

obviously, I did register in `app.php` in the `providers` array. But if I inspect the bindings, there is no service... Any help? This is the second time this happened and earlier, I got away with dumping autoload and config:clear and it is currently under my sail dev environment. I don't want this to happen in prod. So help would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure your configuration isn't cached (`php artisan config:clear`) so that you are making sure that provider you added in the config is being loaded ... also the `provides` method should return the 'binding': `thumbnail`

Comment: Did all that. did not solve the problem and as per the docs, `provides` should return the class, anyway tried your solution, no success. I mean for this Service, I could do a singleton on my own, but would be nicer if it was registered.

Comment: no it should return the binding, which is the string `thumbnail`, you didn't bind a class  name

Comment: Ok so if I go your way and return the bindings name in `provides`, I get `Call to a member function storeThumbnail() on string`. makes sense, because there is no such function on a normal string. thumbnail is perfectly bound in the register method. What worries me more is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Today, it doesn't

Comment: it is a deferred provider so it needs to know what is being provided, in this case you are providing a binding named `thumbnail` ...  why would `thumbnail` resolve as a string if you have the singleton returning an object?

Comment: That is becaue I probably took you too literally and had `provides()` return `['thumbnail']`... For some magical reason it seems to work again. For taking it to prod, I would very much like to know the root cause. Happy to help documenting.

Comment: `provides` is supposed to return `['thumbnail']`, that is the correct thing ... unless you changed your `singleton` closure to return a string instead of an object you shouldn't get such an error